# Django admin false reporting errors for nullable fields

Tags: django

This is my User class:

```
class User(TimeStampedModel, AbstractBaseUser):                                             
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)                                     
    username = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)                    
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)                                       
    mobile_number = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)                             
    bio = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)                                       
    title = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)                                     
    posts = models.IntegerField(default=0)                                                  
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)                                                  
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)                                           
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                           
    last_active_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                    


    objects =  CustomUserManager()                                                          

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'                                                             
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
```

When I try to update the user from admin dashboard I get 'field cannot be empty error' for the following fields: `mobile_number, email, bio, title`

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `blank=True` in your model for those fields.

```
class User(TimeStampedModel, AbstractBaseUser):                                             
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)                                     
    username = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)                    
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)  # add 'blank' argument                                     
    mobile_number = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255, blank=True) # add 'blank' argument                                                          
    bio = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255, blank=True) # add 'blank' argument                                                                     
    title = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255, blank=True) # add 'blank' argument                                                                   
    posts = models.IntegerField(default=0)                                                  
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)                                                  
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)                                           
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                           
    last_active_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                    


    objects =  CustomUserManager()                                                          

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'                                                             
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
```

If a field has `blank=True`, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. Default value for `blank` argument is `False`.

[**Note:**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#field-options) `null` is purely **database-related**, whereas `blank` is **validation-related**.

If a field has `blank=True`, form validation will allow entry of an empty value.

If a field has `null=True`, Django will store empty values as `NULL` in the database.